# Is it possible to set the date of new DateTime with a variable containing a date?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to create an `if statement` that checks to see if the current date is greater than a date set by a user and saved in my `DB`. I have tested a fixed date and it works:

```
if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("2016-02-25 09:00:00")) {
                        echo "test";
                    }
```

However would this work?

```
$PlannedStartDate = $ProjectRow['StartDate'];

if (new DateTime() > new DateTime("$PlannedStartDate 09:00:00")) {
                        echo "test";
                        }
```

$PlannedStartDate = 2016-01-19

Comment: @MateiMihai  Get a life mate, no need to chat shit.

Comment: :)) That's all you understood from my comment? great.. good luck..

Comment: No your comment was comprised of two parts: 1) "I don't know.. would it work? :| you should try it before asking here.. that's how you learn programming." == unnecessary sass. 2) "to answer you shortly: yes" == polite, decent human being. Don't worry there's still time for you to learn how to be the later :)

Comment: I assume everything I wrote.. I'm still considering that you spent too much time asking this question than trying it by yourself.

Comment: Don't worry yourself over how much time someone else spent on something. Very thoughtful of you but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime construct takes two arguments, where second needs to be a DateTimeZone.

So your code is failing due to just that, and a typo. Here is a working one:

```
$PlannedStartDate = "16:00:00";

if (new DateTime() > new DateTime($PlannedStartDate)) {
    echo "test";
}
```